# Flutter change page transition speed/duration in the theme

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-theme

#### How do I change the duration/speed on transitions set in app's theme?

I am able to change the transition animation using a theme for a `MaterialApp`. The example below replaces the default transitions with a `FadeTransition`. When using the fade transition it feels slow and I cannot figure out how to change the duration on transitions set in the theme.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

final themeData = ThemeData(
  pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
    TargetPlatform.iOS: FadeTransitionBuilder(),
    TargetPlatform.android: FadeTransitionBuilder(),
  }),
);

class FadeTransitionBuilder extends PageTransitionsBuilder {
  @override
  Widget buildTransitions<T>(_, __, animation, ___, child) => FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Mobile',
      theme: themeData,
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like this is hardcoded to 300 milliseconds in the flutter source code : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/dev/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page.dart#L61

Answer (score 9):

I could achieve this using named routes which you need to list in your own instance of Navigator provided to the MaterialApp builder.
The initialRoute property of MaterialApp must be removed.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/about':
        return CustomPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => About());
      default:
        return CustomPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Home());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Mobile',
      theme: themeData,
      builder: (context, widget) {
        return Navigator(
          onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CustomPageRoute extends MaterialPageRoute {
  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 1000);

  CustomPageRoute({builder}) : super(builder: builder);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Create this class:

```dart
class MyRoute extends MaterialPageRoute {
  MyRoute({WidgetBuilder builder}) : super(builder: builder);

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(seconds: 3);
}
```

Now, instead of using regular

```dart
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2()));
```

use

```dart
Navigator.push(context, MyRoute(builder: (_) => Page2()));
```

Comment: very similar solution (extending MaterialPageRoute class) but cleaner, less code. It worked well for me - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Better try update the default transition speed in flutter.
in MaterialPageRoute (page.dart) file.

Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 300);

Update this line, Normally it will be 300 Milliseconds set in flutter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

when adding routes in onGenerate route in material app it works fine on mobile  but on flutter web its not allowing to deep link url navigation (like google.com/products ) so its better to change the speed in MaterialPageRoute(page.dart) file for flutter web